# Populate() specify multiple model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to make a `populate()` on a `find()` request but specifying multiple models, so if no occurrence is found on the first specified model the population will make on the second.

**Here is an example of what I would like to do :**

```
const userSch = new Schema({
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    mail: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    }
});

const botSch = new Schema({
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    owner: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
 });

const nspSch = new Schema({
  name: String,
  channels: [channels],
  users: [{
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
    bot: {
      type: Boolean,
    }
  }],
});

const channels = new Schema({
    name: String,
    message: [{
        user: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        },
        content: String,
    }],
});

const nsp = mongoose.model('namespace', nspSch);
const Auth = mongoose.model('users', userSch);
const BotAuth = mongoose.model('bots', botSch);

function returnMs(nspID, channelID, callback) {
  nsp.findOne({'_id': nspID}).populate({
    path: 'channels.message.user',
    model: 'users' || 'bots',
    select: '_id username',
  })
  .exec(function(err, r) {
    ...
  })
}
```

If there is ever an `npm` package, or a solution or even a track to code it, please share it.

*Thank you*

Comment: You're looking for the wrong thing. Look at [Discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) in the documentation instead. You cannot "selectively" choose models, but you can put different types of data in the same collection. You can even make one model appear as many.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not correspond to my case. I added other parts of my code for more precision. Indeed for each `message` in `channels` an item: `user` is completed thanks to a `populate()` which searches in the model/collection users but I would like to be able to specify another model/collection `bots` in case no occurrence is found (in case the user is a bot).

Comment: Some people just don't know how to take a hint. "Cannot" is an immutable term. I told you very clearly you cannot do what you think you want to do, and having some experience with this I can actually see what you really "need" to do and that involves "discriminators" and changing your code and storage so that everything is actually in "one collection" instead of using different models directly. So **cannot** do `users || bots`. But what **discriminators do do** is allow you to have a **things** model ( or whatever you want to call it ) which contains `users and bots` and then you just populate

Comment: Thank you, for your answer I will do that, it's a shame because from a performance point of view it would have been better.
Otherwise, yes I understood that `users || bots` would not work but it was to show you what I wanted to do.
Thank and good day